# Metric_fu - invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metric-fu

Everyday at the end of the day, I run metric_fu in a RoR environment to measure the code quality. Everything worked fine until today...

When I try to run metric_fu, this is my result since today.

```
$ bundle exec metric_fu -r
F, [2013-05-10T17:11:45.980014 #26798] FATAL -- : invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/lib/churn/git_analyzer.rb:16:in `split'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/lib/churn/git_analyzer.rb:16:in `get_diff'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/lib/churn/source_control.rb:37:in `get_updated_files_from_log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/lib/churn/source_control.rb:11:in `get_updated_files_change_info'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/lib/churn/churn_calculator.rb:250:in `parse_logs_for_updated_files'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/lib/churn/churn_calculator.rb:177:in `calculate_revision_data'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/lib/churn/churn_calculator.rb:165:in `block in calculate_revision_changes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/lib/churn/churn_calculator.rb:160:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/lib/churn/churn_calculator.rb:160:in `calculate_revision_changes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/lib/churn/churn_calculator.rb:59:in `analyze'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/lib/churn/churn_calculator.rb:44:in `report'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/bin/churn:32:in `report_churn'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/bin/churn:40:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/main-5.2.0/lib/main/program/class_methods.rb:155:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/main-5.2.0/lib/main/program/class_methods.rb:144:in `catch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/main-5.2.0/lib/main/program/class_methods.rb:144:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/main-5.2.0/lib/main/factories.rb:18:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/main-5.2.0/lib/main/factories.rb:25:in `Main'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/churn-0.0.28/bin/churn:6:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/bin/mf-churn:11:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/bin/mf-churn:11:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/mf-churn:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/mf-churn:19:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/lib/metric_fu/metrics/churn/churn.rb:10:in `analyze': undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/lib/metric_fu/metrics/generator.rb:129:in `block in generate_report'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/lib/metric_fu/metrics/generator.rb:127:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/lib/metric_fu/metrics/generator.rb:127:in `generate_report'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/lib/metric_fu/reporting/report.rb:63:in `add'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/lib/metric_fu/run.rb:25:in `block in run_reports'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/lib/metric_fu/run.rb:23:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/lib/metric_fu/run.rb:23:in `run_reports'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/lib/metric_fu/run.rb:10:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/lib/metric_fu/cli/helper.rb:11:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/lib/metric_fu/cli/client.rb:18:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/metric_fu-4.1.2/bin/metric_fu:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/metric_fu:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/metric_fu:19:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I found an similar question here: https://github.com/jscruggs/metric_fu/issues/61. As a result of the question at GitHub, I created a file named '.metrics' in the root directory of my project, with the following content:

```
MetricFu::Configuration.run do |config|   
  config.syntax_highlighting = false
end
```

Unfortunately this didn't work.

Nothing, except code, has been updated the last few days, this is why is it weird that this error suddenly occurs.

This is my Ruby version:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

It is possible to bypass the issue by disabling churn. You can disable churn by adding `--no-churn`, like this:

```
$ metric_fu -r --no-churn
```

**Edit 2**

Since I added `--no-churn` once, Metric_fu is fully operational again. Even with Churn activated in the next reports while the same code has been analyzed.

Issue on Github has been created: https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu/issues/70

Answer (score 1):

Please enter an issue [on the metric_fu issues page](https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu/issues/new)   (you had the link to the old repo there).   Based on the stack trace, this might actually be an issue in Churn (that metric_fu is not handling).  Please also check out my [how to write a bug report page](https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu/wiki/Issues%3a-Quick-guide-to-writing-good-bug-reports)  I'll work with you on the bug there.

Comment: Thanks, will do that! For now I bypassed the issue by disabling churn. `$ metric_fu -r --no-churn`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting I haven't run into that any other details on the project or file it is crashing on? I could try to debug this in churn, but don't have a lot to go off. You can file the metric_fu issue or a issue with churn directly. I follow both projects so I would try to follow up in either case.

Comment: I added an [issue for metric_fu to output what file it failed processing, if possible](https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu/issues/68)